# Magento 2.1.3: Undefined offset error when exporting all customers via csv

Tags: magento-2.1.3, bug

I tried to export all the customers in the form of csv from a Magento 2.1.3 site.

[image]

But after I clicked export this will be the outcome:

[image]

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/DEVELOPMENT/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/DataProvider/Document.php on line 135

Any ideas what's wrong with this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@MazeStricks,

A similar issue is reported on the Magento forums at:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10573
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2961
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4376

I also faced the same issue while exporting customers from the admin panel via CSV and XML on Magento EE 2.2.3

```
{
  "0": "Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/DataProvider/Document.php on line 136",
  "1": "#0 /vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/DataProvider/Document.php(136): Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/app/wtzyes327l...', 136, Array)\n#1 /vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/DataProvider/Document.php(102): Magento\\Customer\\Ui\\Component\\DataProvider\\Document->setGenderValue()\n#2 /vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/MetadataProvider.php(159): Magento\\Customer\\Ui\\Component\\DataProvider\\Document->getCustomAttribute('gender')\n#3 /vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php(84): Magento\\Ui\\Model\\Export\\MetadataProvider->getRowData(Object(Magento\\Customer\\Ui\\Component\\DataProvider\\Document), Array, Array)\n#4 /vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GridToCsv.php(72): Magento\\Ui\\Model\\Export\\ConvertToCsv->getCsvFile()\n#5 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv->execute()\n#6 /vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#7 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#9 /vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 /generated/code/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GridToCsv/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#13 /vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#14 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#15 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#16 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#17 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#18 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#19 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#20 /pub/index.php(37): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#21 {main}",
  "url": "/admin/mui/export/gridToCsv/key/4b1c73d5e71f0802f16b0380aecd481a7ec5f2b6a45b7006a243d13dd3ce9be4/?filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&search=&namespace=customer_listing&selected=false",
  "script_name": "/index.php"
}
```

For me though, the issue was caused during setting Gender of the customer in "Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Document.php"

at             **$option = $attributeMetadata->getOptions()[$value];**

The following was the piece of code with error:

```
   /**
     * Update customer gender value
     * Method set gender label instead of id value
     * @return void
     */
    private function setGenderValue()
    {
        $value = $this->getData(self::$genderAttributeCode);

        if (!$value) {
            $this->setCustomAttribute(self::$genderAttributeCode, 'N/A');
            return;
        }

        try {
            $attributeMetadata = $this->customerMetadata->getAttributeMetadata(self::$genderAttributeCode);
            $option = $attributeMetadata->getOptions()[$value];
            $this->setCustomAttribute(self::$genderAttributeCode, $option->getLabel());
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $this->setCustomAttribute(self::$genderAttributeCode, 'N/A');
        }
    }
```

The fixed code was :

```
   /**
     * Update customer gender value
     * Method set gender label instead of id value
     * @return void
     */
    private function setGenderValue()
    {
        $value = $this->getData(self::$genderAttributeCode);


        if (!$value) {
            $this->setCustomAttribute(self::$genderAttributeCode, 'N/A');
            return;
        }

        try {
            $attributeMetadata = $this->customerMetadata->getAttributeMetadata(self::$genderAttributeCode);

            foreach ($attributeMetadata->getOptions() as $option) {
                if ($option->getValue() == $value) {
                    $this->setCustomAttribute(self::$genderAttributeCode, $option->getLabel());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $this->setCustomAttribute(self::$genderAttributeCode, 'N/A');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Shahab, Thanks for this one. I'll try this.